# Emulating NDEF NFC Tag on Android phone -> Reading with iPhone/iOS core-nfc

Tags: android, ios, nfc

I use a `HostApduService` on Android(7) to emulate an NFC forum type 4 (`NDEF`) tag.

Reading the `NDEF` text message works reliably from android, I ran into the following issues though:

- When I scan the emulating phone with NXP TagInfo from another Android device, Google Play opens up since it is also listening, but the `NDEF` tag always gets scanned successfully.
- Reading the Tag using NXP TagInfo on an iPhone(7) as a reader is different: The core `NFC` API looks very limited, and scanning has to be initiated by the user, accompanied by a "ready to scan" dialog. When I hold the iPhone to the Android Device, sometimes the dialog closes with the message "`NFC` session expired" (about 50% of the tries). When I lock the emulating Android phone, the `NDEF` service still runs, and the iPhone can scan the Tag with a 100% success rate.

I think I already fixed the first issue using `ForegroundDispatch` (the Tag Emulation is only needed when the Emulating app is shown on the screen). However, the iPhone still cancels scanning sometimes. I suppose this could also be caused by the Android phone trying to connect to the iPhone's HCE/ApplePay/whatever is there.

So I believe the cause of my problem is Android scanning for all kinds of tags while `NFC` is enabled.

Is there a way to disable actively scanning for passive tags from an app, while still running the `HostApduService` that emulates an `NFC` tag?

(I will update this question as soon as I get the core `NFC` error messages.)

Comment: Any update on this with the updates to iOS 13?